# kompose up fail with unable to build image

Tags: docker-compose, kubectl, minikube, kompose

I am trying to convert my docker-compose.yml file which works perfectly fine to run it in minikube with kubectl.

I have installed minikube, kubectl and kompose, when I try to run I get the following error:

```
 C:\Users\test\Downloads\get-string-master\get-string-master> .\kompose-windows-amd64.exe -f .\docker-compose.yml up
INFO Build key detected. Attempting to build and push image 'mainapp'
INFO Building image 'mainapp' from directory 'mainapp'
FATA Error while deploying application: k.Transform failed: Unable to build Docker image for service mainapp: open \tmp\kompose-image-build-399841535: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:

mainapp:
    container_name: mainapp
    restart: always
    build: ./mainapp
    image: mainapp
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    command: gunicorn -c gunicorn.ini mainapp.application:app

reverseapp:
    container_name: reverseapp
    restart: always
    build: ./reverseapp
    image: reverseapp
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - mainapp
    command: gunicorn -c gunicorn.ini reverseapp.application:app

 nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    image: nginx1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - reverseapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by exception you have posted:

> \tmp\kompose-image-build-399841535: The system cannot find the path
>   specified

I can suggest you to check that this directory exists and your user has sufficient permissions to access it.

Comment: I created manually and it fails with "FATA Error while deploying application: k.Transform failed: Unable to build Docker image for service mainapp: Unable to build image. For more output, use -v or --verbose when converting.: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: socket: An address incompatible with the requested
protocol was used."